# How to stop InteractiveViewer scaling and panning till the child is fully loaded?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am using one Stateful widget where scaling and panning are two states.
Initially my states are false.
As soon as my ComplexBigWidget is fully loaded I am setting scaling and panning states to true.
But this re-renders my ComplexBigWidget again and one loop is created.

```
InteractiveViewer(
          scaleEnabled: scaling,
          panEnabled: panning,
          maxScale: 30.0,
          boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(double.infinity),
          minScale: 0.1,
          constrained: false,
          transformationController: Constants.controller,
          child: **ComplexBigWidget**()
)
```

I used one way to stop rebuilding loop by this code:

```
setScalingAndPanning(bool flag) {
  if(scaling == false){
    setState(() {
      scaling = flag;
      panning = flag;
    });
  }
}
```

But in this approach twice ComplexBigWidget is rendered.

how should I tackle this scenario ?

Comment: Why not just make InteractiveViewer the top level widget in ComplexBigWidget? You can use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to help with displaying it.

Comment: i can't as i need show complex widget first then draw lines to connect the widgets and do some animation.

The complex widget is successfully building but if a user try to scale or pan then draw lines and animation is working divergently.

Comment: so draw the lines transformed by `Constants.controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented loader_overlay till the complex widget is rendering.